# Recommendations for a physics-related book for a child?

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference

So it's that time of year again, where one must buy gifts for all children in sight.

I want to buy a book, related to physics, ideally, for my girlfriend's sister. What books are educational and informational for a 9-year-old? At that age I was reading Stephen Hawking's "Universe in a Nutshell", so I know I'm not a good test audience.

Two years ago I bought her a book of photographs of planets, galaxies and nebulae, and I was quite pleased to see (a few months or so ago) that the book was practically falling apart(as this implies it has been used, at all :) ). I'm wondering what direction I can move to from here. I want to keep her thinking! No matter what she ends up doing as a job, I want her to be inquisitive, and question the standard assumptions in her life. How can I further this nefarious goal?

Answer (score 2):

Richard Dawkins' *The Magic of Reality* does a good job describing the scientific method as a whole. Gamow's *Mr Tompkins* books or *One Two Three...Infinity* might be interesting to children that age.